# Sorting mysql row data to get only a specific id

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table as shown below

```
id | t_id | u_id
---+------+------
1  | 2    | 2
2  | 1    | 2
3  | 1    | 1
4  | 2    | 2
5  | 1    | 1
```

I am trying to get all t_id with u_id of 2 but once without the t_id ever having a u_id of 1 in the history of the whole table.

I tried

```
SELECT
    C_Name, count(*) as count 
FROM tenter 
WHERE C_Date = '20200127' AND L_TID = '2';
```

But this gives me the record of all L_TID = 2 and does not filter out those with previous record of L_tid = 1.

Expected result: get all U_ID without the previous history of L_TID = 1, it should get only those without ever having L_tid =1.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

One method is aggregation and a `having` clause:

```
select t_id
from tenter t
group by t_id
having sum(u_id = 2) > 0 and   -- has "2"
       sum(u_id = 1) = 0;      -- does not have "1"
```

If you have another table of `t` values, then `exists`/`not exists` might be more efficient:

```
select t.t_id
from t
where exists (select 1 from tenter tt where tt.t_id = t.t_id and tt.u_id = 2) and
      not exists (select 1 from tenter tt where tt.t_id = t.t_id and tt.u_id = 1);
```

Comment: Thanks @Gordon it solved my problem. Thank you so much guys

Answer (score 2):

I think you want `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from tenter t
where 
    u_id = 2
    and not exists (
        select 1 from tenter t1 where t1.t_id = t.t_id and t1.u_id = 1
    )
```

You can also use aggregation, if you just want a list of `t_id`s. If `1` and `2` are the only possible values, you can just do:

```
select t_id
from tenter t
group by t_id
having min(u_id) = 2
```

If there are other possible values:

```
having max(u_id = 1) = 0 and max(u_id = 2) = 1
```